# Py2exe not bundling dlls of PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

I am using pyqt4 in python.
When I set the bundle_files settings in py2exe `"bundle_files":1`, I don't get a single executable file.
All the dlls of PyQt are not bundled in the exe for some reason.
These are the Dlls that are not bundled (LIBEAY32.dll, MSVCR100.dll, QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, QtNetwork4.dll, QtWebKit4.dll, SSLEAY32.dll)